# Duplicate banner does not contain link to valid question

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315705/what-is-the-difference-between-i-i-in-for-loop-java) appears to be marked as a duplicate, but the blue banner does not include a link. Instead, it shows a confusing closed note, and actual dupe links are provided further down the page in a yellow banner:

[image]

I'm not sure if this is a bug that was introduced with the banner overhaul?

Comment: Finally I have a chance to test my userscript. Lets me re-close old dupes as new dupes without having to unlock the post first!